# Compare the keys of two dictionaries and create a dictionary with key, value pairs that does not match the key in the other dictionary - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to compare the keys between `dict_1` and `dict_2` and create a `new_dict` that contains only the non-matched keys and their corresponding values. I have two dicts like this:

```
dict_1 = {'a':'1', 'b':'1', 'c': None}
dict_2 = {'d': '1', 'a': '2'}
```

I want the output to be like: `a` and `a` matches so I want it to be excluded in the `new_dict`.

```
new_dict = {'b':'1', 'c': None, 'd': '1'}
```

I tried this:

```
new_dict = {}
for key in dict_1.items():
for key2 in dict_2.items():
    if key == key2:
```

But I'm not sure how to proceed from here or maybe this is not the right way to do it. Please Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform set-like operations on the result of `dict.keys`:

> For set-like views, all of the operations defined for the abstract base class [`collections.abc.Set`](https://docs.python.org/release/3.3.0/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Set) are available (for example, `==`, `<`, or `^`).

So you can do something like

```
dict_1 = {'a':'1', 'b':'1', 'c': None}
dict_2 = {'d': '1', 'a': '2'}

keys = dict_1.keys() ^ dict_2.keys()

new_dict = {k: dict_1.get(k, dict_2.get(k)) for k in keys}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to get the keys of each dictionary, and find the unique ones. I did it as sets. Take a look:

```
# your dictionaries
dict_1 = {'a':'1', 'b':'1', 'c': None}
dict_2 = {'d': '1', 'a': '2'}

# find their keys
dict_1_keys = set(dict_1.keys())
dict_2_keys = set(dict_2.keys())
# find unique keys
unique_keys = (dict_1_keys.union(dict_2_keys)) - (dict_1_keys.intersection(dict_2_keys))

dict_results = {}

for key in unique_keys:
    if dict_1.get(key) is not None:
        dict_results[key] = dict_1.get(key)
    else:
        dict_results[key] = dict_2.get(key)

print(dict_results)
```

Comment: You've implemented `symmetric_difference`, a.k.a. `^` for your set. The operations you're doing are functionally fine, but superfluously reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Checking `if dict_1.get(key) is not None:` will give you the wrong answer because one of the dicts contains a valid None value. Use `if key in dict_1:` instead.

Comment: Strictly speaking the None thing doesn't cause a bug, because if the key exists in one dictionary then it doesn't exist in the other, so `get` on the other dictionary returns None and that's the correct value to include. But better to write `key in dict_1` when that's logically what you want to test; avoid tricky code that seems to work by accident.